# Calculate the output of a single-layer neuron with weight bias?

Tags: neural-network, perceptron

Normally, the output of a single layer perceptron with 3 inputs is calculated as W<sub>1</sub>X<sub>1</sub> + W<sub>2</sub>X<sub>2</sub> + W<sub>3</sub>X<sub>3</sub>, but what if I had a bias weight W with a fixed input, how do I go about that?